# SSMS Query slow join

Tags: t-sql, ssms

Tried to join three tables: car, car_and_engine, and engine. The second table, car_and_engine, connects the cars and their engines. A car type has up to three possible engine types. The query is significantly slower than expected (based on experience with similar operations in other languages). Is there anything **terribly inefficient** about this code?

```
select engine_type, AVG(horsepower) into #horsepower_by_engine_type
from TRANSPORT.dbo.engine
group by engine_type
go

with temp as(select * from TRANSPORT.dbo.car left join TRANSPORT.dbo.car_and_engine on TRANSPORT.dbo.car_and_engine.car_type_y = TRANSPORT.dbo.car.car_type_x)

select * from temp left join #horsepower_by_engine_type as e1 on temp.engine_type_1 = e1.engine_type
left join #horsepower_by_engine_type as e2 on temp.engine_type_2 = e2.engine_type
left join #horsepower_by_engine_type as e3 on temp.engine_type_3 = e3.engine_type
```

Comment: What is "expected" and what is "slower"? Presumably you mean the second of the two queries. Please share the table schema and its indexes, also the actual execution plan (PasteThePlan).

Comment: That query shouldn't even run; your CTE `temp` has at least 2 columns called `car_type`. This tell me that you aren't giving us the *actual* query.

Comment: Temp tables are notoriously slow. Just make one query and it should run much quicker, even with the aggregate.

Comment: @tgolisch curious why you believe *Temp tables are notoriously slow* - often an intermediary temp table can greatly improve query performance for many reasons such as providing the optimiser with accurate statistics to drive a better downstream execution plan.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL with indexes, sample data and expected results help us help you. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will include an execution plan in the future. Your high-level review helped me improve the code. After repeated tests, however, it points towards the server not allocating enough computing power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a temp table (except when you are doing some diagnostics). You could replace your temp table syntax with an inline-view.

```
with temp as(select * from TRANSPORT.dbo.car left join TRANSPORT.dbo.car_and_engine on TRANSPORT.dbo.car_and_engine.car_type = TRANSPORT.dbo.car.car_type)

select * from temp left join 
  (select engine_type, AVG(horsepower) 
   from TRANSPORT.dbo.engine
   group by engine_type) as e1 on temp.engine_type_1 = e1.engine_type
left join 
  (select engine_type, AVG(horsepower) 
   from TRANSPORT.dbo.engine
   group by engine_type) as e2 on temp.engine_type_2 = e2.engine_type
left join 
  (select engine_type, AVG(horsepower) 
   from TRANSPORT.dbo.engine
   group by engine_type) as e3 on temp.engine_type_3 = e3.engine_type
```

Better still, you could put your summary into your CTE

```
with temp as (select * from TRANSPORT.dbo.car left join TRANSPORT.dbo.car_and_engine on TRANSPORT.dbo.car_and_engine.car_type = TRANSPORT.dbo.car.car_type),
     avgHP as (select engine_type, AVG(horsepower) from TRANSPORT.dbo.engine group by engine_type)

select * from temp left join avgHP as e1 on temp.engine_type_1 = e1.engine_type
left join avgHP as e2 on temp.engine_type_2 = e2.engine_type
left join avgHP as e3 on temp.engine_type_3 = e3.engine_type
```

Comment: The use of CTE to avoid temporary tables is neat - thank you!